# Add class to group inner container

Tags: php, functions, block-editor, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add class to my group block, to the container "*wp-block-group__inner-container*". I know it's possible to add a div before with *render_block*, but I want to add bootstrap class like this :

```
<div class="wp-block-group row">
    <div class="wp-block-group__inner-container col-12 col-lg-10 offset-lg-1 py-3">
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do this ?

Thank you !

Comment: it's weird that this question has a video for it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lzA7yxDcvs

Answer (score -1):

Would using your group class work?

```
.row > .wp-group-block__inner-container { }
```

I don't know how to add a class to the inner container but figured I would propose this alternative, hope it helps !